# Wrap text around big subfigure at the bottom row

Tags: captions, wrapfigure, subfig

I wanted to wrap text around the big subfigure at the bottom row of the figure. The top row 4 subfigure are ok, the spacing works. But when I wrap text around the big subfigure `(e)` at the bottom(the name `(e)` is missing too), the caption splits the paragraph. Also the caption should go to the write under `(e)`.

The MWE:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub1.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{-0.25cm}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub2.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace*{-1.05cm}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub3.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace*{-0.25cm}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub4.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\bigskip
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub5.png}
    \caption{} 
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
```

\caption{Registration visualized. }
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]

[image]

Comment: I figure out the `gap` is due to `\bigskip` so I removed it from MWE.

Comment: How far to the right?  Under the image, or just `\raggedleft`?

Comment: @JohnKormylo under the image like typical captions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This puts the figure caption under the last image & subcaption. Note that some of the text is inside the figure and may float relative to the rest of the text.

Interestingly, when I put `\subcaption` and `\caption` in the same group, the `\caption` turns into another `\subcaption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export, draft]{adjustbox}% for valign
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering% not used
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub1.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub2.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub3.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub4.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}\vspace{\floatsep}
    
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr 0.6\textwidth-\columnsep}
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}% to include figure \caption
      \begin{subfigure}[t]{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub5.png}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}
      \caption{Registration visualized. }
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

---

This version uses a separate figure and wrapfig with `\ContinuedFloat`.  If the figure floats to the next page, so should the wrapfig, although at the start of a new paragraph instead of the end of the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export, draft]{adjustbox}% for valign
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering% not used
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub1.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub2.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub3.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub4.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}% automatic \textfloatssep
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.4\textwidth}
    \ContinuedFloat
    \vskip-\intextsep
    \vbox{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub5.png}
      \subcaption{}}
    \caption{Registration visualized. }
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

---

This puts everything into one wrapfigure.  It deliberately overlaps the left side then adds a gap in the text to match.  Note that it is important to **not** move the first baseline, so the gap is implemented below the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export, draft]{adjustbox}% for valign
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\overlap}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
  \sbox0{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}% measure first row
    \centering% not used
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub1.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub2.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub3.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub4.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{minipage}}%
  \setlength{\overlap}{\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0+\intextsep-\ht\strutbox}% compute overlap distance
  \global\overlap=\overlap
  \hfill\llap{\usebox0}\par\vskip\floatsep% overlap left side of page
  \vbox{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Images/SpecificAim3/sub5.png}
    \subcaption{}}
  \caption{Registration visualized. }
  \vskip-\overlap
\end{wrapfigure}

\strut\vspace{\overlap}\par% create gap below baseline
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first code moves the figures in different pages. But the second one works perfect. 
Thanks!

Comment: The first solution uses one figure.  It does however move the text.